# How to utilize GET response from WSClient in Play Framework 2.5 with Java?

Tags: java, playframework

I'm trying to make a get request from Play Framework to another server and save the response body in database. All the answers to similar questions show how to send retrieved data through controller action. But I want to make a request from actor and save the response in DB.
Here is the code of Actor class:

```
public class TestActor extends UntypedActor {
    @Inject
    WSClient ws;
    @Inject
    ExecutionContextExecutor exec;

    public static Props props = Props.create(TestActor.class);
    public int i = 0;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object msg) throws Exception {

        if (msg instanceof String && msg == "doTest") {
            Logger.info("I am doing test " + ++i);
            CompletionStage<JsonNode> jsonPromise = ws.url("http://localhost:3000").get().thenApply(WSResponse::asJson);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand how to process that `jsonPromise` further. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html)? You just need to use `thenAccept` to run your database insertion code.

Comment: @4castle , I tried using _jsonPromise.thenAccept(jsonNode -> Logger.info(jsonNode.toString()));_. But it gives runtime error - 
[error] a.a.OneForOneStrategy - null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Comment: How about `thenAcceptAsync`?

Comment: Same result. I think this issue is due to some behavior of Actor, because same code with _thenAccept_ works in controller action. But I'm unable to do this in scheduled Actor.

Comment: Above mentioned error was due to wrong dependency injection of Actor used while scheduling this actor. It worked when I created the actor instance as follows - @Named("test-actor") ActorRef testActor.
Answer for this question should be `thenAccept`. Thanks @4castle.